# Right-click not working on 12.04[Acer Travelmate]

Tags: 12.04, hardware, acer, trackpad

For the past 2 hours, the right click button on my laptop (Acer Travelmate) is not working. Upon using it, nothing happens, no menu pops up (as it normally should), it remains static as if no command was registered.

Any ideas on how this can sorted?

Answer (score 1):

my current office-supplied laptop is the Acer Travelmate x483. I just found out that the right-click for the travelmate is like the macbook pro that you have to tap two (2) fingers, then the right-click menu appears. Thanks.

Comment: thank you for your answer. uhm, i have a dedicated hardware button for the right click which wasn't responding, so i believe that for some reason the drivers had crashed.